# Is it possible to fetch the web page by creating Access point through ESP8266?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Sorry For asking such a basic question . But I am new to this , and just started learning .My question is-

Is it possible to fetch the web page by creating Access point through ESP8266 ?

for eg- if I created access Point and go to "192.168.4.1/www.google.com" , 
will I be able to fetch the web page and store in my memory ?

Answer (score 1):

The ESP8266 is a device which allows a developer to have WiFi capabilities for his projects. It allows the developer to create a device (a microcontroller device like an Arduino or atmega on another board) which will be able to connect to a network via WiFi; either by connecting to an existing Access Point or by establishing a new Access Point. By doing this the developer can have his device communicate with other devices on that network.

If you setup your ESP8266 as an Access Point then other devices will be able to connect to it by getting onto that Access Point.

If you setup your ESP8266 to another Access Point then of course it will get onto that other AP and as such be on its network.

Now the important part; The ESP8266 in itself is not a router or proxy. If you want it to behave in that way then you have to either change the "user firmware" (One can write so-called firmware for the ESP8266 which is a program that runs on the ESP8266 which you can tweak as you want) or you can create another device or use an Arduino to act in a certain way. For instance an Arduino can be programmed by you to use the ESP8266 to act a certain way. So basically you must do the software which will accept request from a client on a network and then you will connect to another host, locally or on the internet and then forward whatever you receive back to the client.

Keep in mind that unfortunately it is a bit more intricate than that and you will have to do a lot of research to find out how routing or proxies actually work. There are also security features involved which complicates it even further. I personally do not think it is even worthwhile to do that with something as small as Arduino and ESP8266